# Editing the /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist file

Tags: permission, plist

I need to `vim` the file found at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist` but the permissions will not allow it. Even when I run `sudo vim /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist` and enter my password, VIM throws me a warning and says that I'm editing a readonly file. Any ideas how to do this?

I'm running OS X 10.11 El Capitain.

Comment: Please add your system version

Answer (score 5):

Some [paths and applications](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) in El Capitan are protected by System Integrity Protection. Even root can't modify the files. You first have to disable SIP before editing or modifying them.

1. Reboot your Mac to Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
2. Click Utilities -> Terminal.
3. In the Terminal window, enter in `csrutil disable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Restart your Mac
5. Modify the file(s)
6. Reboot your Mac to Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
7. Click Utilities -> Terminal.
8. In the Terminal window, enter in `csrutil enable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
9. Restart your Mac

Comment: This method is not working for macOS Big Sur. Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to enable [PF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PF_%28firewall%29) at startup, you can also try the following*.

In System Preferences / Security & Privacy / Firewall Options..., check "Enable stealth mode" and turn on Firewall.

Somehow this enables PF. You can check by running `sudo pfctl -s info`.

*Tested on High Sierra and Mojave

Answer (score 0):

In Mac Catalina 10.15.6,
I couldn't edit com.apple.pfctl.plist after running `csrutil disable` and restart OS.

I restart to Recover mode
-> execute `csrutil disable` in terminal
-> Restart to Recover mode
-> then mount OS Volume by Disk util
-> then edit com.apple.pfctl.plist in terminal
-> then executed `csrutil disable`
-> restart to normal mode
-> done

Comment: Why do you need to edit this file? Might there be another method of achieving the same end result?

Comment: I need to enable pfctl by default after turning on computer.